# which packages are compiled into gnumail-providers.jar, and what are JAR the dependencies?

Tags: java, ant, makefile, classpath, gnu

In order to compile `gnu.mail.provider` and `gnu.mail.treeutil` **into** `gnumail-providers.jar` what are the dependencies and what are the packages which should be compiled?

*More importantly, are those the packages which go into this JAR? **And**, what needs to be on the classpath to build this JAR correctly?*

Below follows what I think GNU is doing.  GNU makes all their projects build from make, so for [classpathx](http://savannah.gnu.org/svn/?group=classpathx) the [instructions](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.classpath.extensions.javamail/692) are:

```
svn co svn://svn.savannah.gnu.org/classpathx/trunk classpathx cd
classpathx/activation ./configure && make && sudo make install cd
../inetlib ./configure && make && sudo make install cd ../mail ./configure
&& make && sudo make install
```

1.) what are the JAR dependencies for building `gnumail-providers.jar`?

2.) which source code package(s) should be compiled to build `gnumail-providers.jar`?

Looking at what Ubuntu does, `apt-get install libgnuinet-java libgnujaf-java libgnumail-java` installs:

```
/usr/share/java/inetlib.jar
/usr/share/java/activation.jar
/usr/share/java/gnumail-providers.jar
/usr/share/java/gnumail.jar
```

It's a little bit odd because `libgnumail-java` installs both `gnumail.jar` and `gnumail-providers.jar`, and I'm not quite sure why those are separate, and what the dependencies are.

`jar -tf /usr/share/java/gnumail.jar` shows packages `gnu.mail` as well as `javax.mail`, so that JAR is limited to the source code for those packages, at most?

Alternately,

`jar -tf /usr/share/java/gnumail-providers.jar` is more specific, with `gnu.mail.providers` and `gnu.mail.treeutil`, which all seems a bit odd.

Why are **some**, but not all, `gnu.mail` packages built into a seperate JAR from the main JAR?
The over-ridden (if that's the correct term) `javax.mail` is packaged in the same JAR as `gnu.mail`, but why?

That `gnu.mail` is split and packaged into two separate JAR's seems unusual, as does the way `javax.mail` ends up with `gnu.mail` and not in a JAR of its own.

In a larger way, is this a normal way of packaging JAR's?

In the more practical sense, in order to compile `gnu.mail.provider` and `gnu.mail.treeutil` **into** `gnumail-providers.jar` what are the dependencies and what are the packages which should be compiled?

It seems odd that a subset of a package hierarchy is compiled into a JAR to sit alongside its brethren, but is that what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the source code here:

- http://svn.sv.gnu.org/viewvc/trunk/activation/?root=classpathx

Then read the [installation instructions](http://svn.sv.gnu.org/viewvc/trunk/activation/INSTALL?root=classpathx&view=markup) and ANT is not supported by this build:

> Ant build
>
> A simple Ant buildfile is included for platforms where GNU Make is not
>   installed. This buildfile is not officially supported and may not provide
>   options available during the standard autotools-based installation.

I took a peek and the [build file](http://svn.sv.gnu.org/viewvc/trunk/activation/build.xml?root=classpathx&view=markup) is only responsible for building the "activation.jar" file.

Comment: is this http://svn.sv.gnu.org/viewvc/trunk/mail/build.xml?revision=1156&root=classpathx&view=markup  it!?  I see `<target name='javamail.providers' depends='javamail.providers.init,smtp.ok,imap.ok,pop3.ok,nntp.ok,mbox.ok,maildir.ok'/>`  which looks very, very promising!

Comment: That's another build file in another directory. If this code is normally built using "make", it comes as no surprise to me that it's hard to build using ANT.... I would recommend contacting the developers who own the code.